# Un-tabify three QDockWidgets programmatically

Tags: qt, qt5, qdockwidget

I have an application with three dock widgets. Those are created by the following code:

```
dock = new QDockWidget(tr("Some title"));
dock->setWidget(some_widget);
dock->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu);
dock->setFeatures(QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable | QDockWidget::DockWidgetFloatable);
addDockWidget(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea, dock);
```

`dock2` and `dock3` are then tabified by

```
tabifyDockWidget(dock1, dock2);
tabifyDockWidget(dock2, dock3);
```

The window then looks like this:
[image: Tabbed docks]

I can arrange the docks side by side by dragging and dropping them, so that the window looks  like this:
[image: side-by-side docks]

I'd like to do this programmatically, but I can't figure out how. When doing a

```
splitDockWidget(dock1, dock2, Qt::Horizontal);
```

nothing happens. When doing

```
splitDockWidget(dock1, dock2, Qt::Vertical);
```

`dock1` and `dock2` disappear, and only `dock3` is still visible:
[image: dock1 and dock2 invisible]

After manually dragging it out of the main window and back in, the window looks like this:
[image: wrongly arranged docks]

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem is to which dockarea the docks are attached to. I added

```
setDockNestingEnabled(true);
```

and the following fuctions, which do the job by first changing the dockarea if needed:

```
void MainWindow::attachDocks(Qt::DockWidgetArea area)
{
    m_playersDock->setFloating(false);
    m_scoreDock->setFloating(false);
    m_rankingDock->setFloating(false);
    addDockWidget(area, m_playersDock);
    addDockWidget(area, m_scoreDock);
    addDockWidget(area, m_rankingDock);
}

void MainWindow::arrangeTabified()
{
    attachDocks(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea);
    tabifyDockWidget(m_playersDock, m_scoreDock);
    tabifyDockWidget(m_scoreDock, m_rankingDock);
}

void MainWindow::arrangeHorizontally()
{
    attachDocks(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea);
    splitDockWidget(m_playersDock, m_scoreDock, Qt::Horizontal);
    splitDockWidget(m_scoreDock, m_rankingDock, Qt::Horizontal);
}

void MainWindow::arrangeVertically()
{
    attachDocks(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
    splitDockWidget(m_playersDock, m_scoreDock, Qt::Vertical);
    splitDockWidget(m_scoreDock, m_rankingDock, Qt::Vertical);
}

void MainWindow::arrangeOwnWindow()
{
    m_playersDock->setFloating(true);
    m_scoreDock->setFloating(true);
    m_rankingDock->setFloating(true);
}
```

Comment: `setDockNestingEnabled(true);` is not needed when alligning the dockwidgets programmatically